# Answer deleted when posted to duplicate question

Tags: support, duplicates, deleted-answers

I came across the question [Why does the melting point of water decreases with increase in pressure?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653231)
and answered it. I found a day later that an earlier, almost identical question had been asked by the same author, so I improved my answer and submitted it as an answer to the earlier question. That (later) answer, which I prefer, has been deleted (from the earlier question) by a moderator. How do I get that answer back and the other deleted?

Answer (score 6):

The problem here was the duplicate questions: one of them should have been closed.

Since both versions of the question had upvoted answers, I’ve merged them, and the answers are migrated. Feel free to edit your live answer on the merged question into a form that you’re happy with.

We very rarely merge questions — this is probably the first one I’ve done in 2021.